# Locating pip configurations outside of pip.conf

Tags: rhel, pip

I am trying to modify pip (version 9) to exclusively retrieve python packages from my Artifactory server instead of pypi.

my /etc/pip.conf file has only configurations to hit my Artifactory repository however when analyzing network packets I can see I am still retrieving packages from pypi.org

running the `locate pip.conf` command shows only my /etc/pip.conf file is present. I have also checked for a hidden pip.conf file in my home directory. Is there any other configuration files pip reads from when retrieving Python packages that may be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
pip config -v list
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I am on pip version 9 so do not have access to the config command. Unfortunately I cannot update it either

Comment: Ok, you might want to add that information to the answer.